# Check whether file name already exists in a folder or not?

Tags: c++, linux, compiler-construction, g++

In C++ I need to check whether a entered file name exists in that folder or not. I'm writing code for Linux, using the g++ compiler.
please help guys :)

I saw this code somewhere on net for my problem but I strongly feel it wont serve my purpose:

```
ofstream fout(filename);
if(fout)
{
cout<<"File name already exists";
return 1;
}
```

Comment: Change `ofstream` to `ifstream` would be better.

Comment: What did you try? you have to try on your own before asking for help

Answer (score 4):

You can do this by testing with an `ifstream`, but there is a subtle difference between using that and the C level `stat()` interface.

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cerr << "Filepath required.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream fs(argv[1]);
    if (fs.is_open()) {
        fs.close();
        cout << "ifstream says file exists.\n";
    } else cout << "ifstream says file does not exist.\n";

    struct stat info;
    if ((stat(argv[1], &info)) == -1) {
        if (errno == ENOENT) cout << "stat() says file does not exist.\n";
        else cout << "stat() says " << strerror(errno) << endl;
    } else cout << "stat() says file exists.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

- If you run this on a file that exists *and you have read permission on*, you'll get the same answer both ways.
- If you run this on a file that does not exist, you get the same answer both ways.
- If you run this on a file that exists *but you do not have read permissions on*, **you'll get two different answers**.  `fstream` will say the file does not exist, but `stat()` will say it does.  Note that if you run `ls` in the same directory, it will show the file, even though you cannot read it; it does exist.

So if the last case is not significant -- i.e., a file you can't read might as well not exist -- then use the `ifstream` test.  However, if it is important, then use the `stat()` test.  See `man 2 stat` (the `2` is important) for more, and remember, to use it you need:

```
#include <cerrno>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
```

`cerrno` is required to check `errno` if `stat()` fails, which can happen. For example, if read permission on a directory in the path is denied, then `stat()` will fail and `errno` will be equal to `EACCES`; if you try it with the above program you'll get `stat() says Permission denied`.  **This does not mean the file exists.** It means you can't check whether it exists or not.

Beware, if you have not used `errno` before: You must check immediately on a failed call, before you make any others which may set it differently.  It is, however, thread safe.

Comment: @didierc You can't stat or open a file in a directory you can't read, even if you know it exists, you have the exact path, and the file is world readable.  In this case, `stat()` *will* fail, and errno will `== EACCES`.  I.e., an unreadable directory in a path is an absolute wall.

Comment: @didierc Indeed.  I've added some stuff in the last few paragraphs about this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be cross-platform and C++'y I recommend the [Boost Filesystem library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm).

For your purposes I think something similar to this Boost sample code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  path p (argv[1]);   // p reads clearer than argv[1] in the following code

  if (exists(p))    // does p actually exist?
  {
    if (is_regular_file(p))        // is p a regular file?   
      cout << p << " size is " << file_size(p) << '\n';

    else if (is_directory(p))      // is p a directory?
      cout << p << "is a directory\n";

    else
      cout << p << "exists, but is neither a regular file nor a directory\n";
  }
  else
    cout << p << "does not exist\n";

  return 0;
}
```

would do the job.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is fstat:
http://codewiki.wikidot.com/c:system-calls:fstat